# Must update every page on Magento 2.2.2 before it shows correctly

Tags: magento2.2.2

I freshly installed Magento 2.2.2.

Before a page works, I have to load it once and then refresh it. This is the case for both the admin panel and CMS pages.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Comment: This is due to your page being cached in your browser. Refresh your browser cache and it should load correctly the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The static resources are being materialized in the public folder when you call the page the first time.
The second time they exist and that's why it loads faster and better.
Run this in the command line and it should make it load faster.
`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`

Comment: I figured that was the case. However, two things don't sound quite right: 1) shouldn't the pages just load slower? instead, they load without a significant part of the JS & CSS files; 2) shouldn't the pages just work after the first time I load them? (they don't, I have to fiddle around and reload quite a bit before all the buttons start working). 
Oh and by the way I already run that command (I found it in the documentation), but it didn't run successfully in "default" mode. (It run correctly, and fixed the issue, in "production" mode, which is something!)